# Entity Framework / Database design - Updating data but keeping links to previous data

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-4

I've learning ASP.Net and Entity Framework 4 by a practical example. To trial this, I'm using the example of `User` sending in devices for `Repair`. They create an account online, add in a set of `Details` (address, phone, fax etc), and create the return form (`RMA`) online.

The concept I am struggling with, is assigning `Details` to the `Returns`. A `Return` has a set of `Details`, one for contact, delivery and billing. These can be foreign keys to the `Detail` table, as shown below.

The problem is, that if a `User` edits their `Details` online, it will update the `Details` used on the `Return`. This is not the desired behaviour. The `Return` should uses the `Details` which were available at the time it was created.

The question is, how do you make the entity framework create a new `Detail` object, instead of updating the existing one. That is if the user updates `Detail` 23 with a new postcode, `Detail` 23 is not changed, instead a new `Detail` is created (i.e. 45). `Detail` 23 is removed from the `User`, and the new `Detail` 45 is added to the `User`. Whilst an existing `RMA` using `Detail` 23 is unaffected, meanings if you query the `RMA` you get the details which were supplied at the time it was created.

If on reading this question, you think the concept is flawed, and instead the DB should be designed differently (i.e. copying `Detail` data to columns in `RMA` table, or adding in a form of composite key to `Detail` table to create a history of revisions). I'm happy to listen to those wise words as well.

[image: ERD of RMA System]

Comment: You should ask yourself the question: who owns detail #23? It should be either User or RMA, not both. If it is RMA it would represent the user details as applicable to the specific RMA, if is User it would represent user details independent of any RMA.

Comment: The UserID refers to the user that created the RMA. However its likely that the RMA can be viewed by several people, i.e. Staff members who need to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have complex data editing rules that are outside of the realm of basic CRUD, then you essentially have two choices with Entity Framework.

1. Give up on simple data binding and build your special handling into a business rule layer that sits between your GUI and your data layer (EF).
2. Give up the simplicity of a thin EF layer and put your special data handling rules into stored procedures and then set the CRUD procedures in your EF model to the stored procs you've defined.

Either way, you are making a compromise because no ORM, EF or otherise, can accomodate both "codeless" databinding and non-trivial CRUD processing.  Pick the approach that suits your project and perferences the best.  Some people can't live without databinding, some can't live with it.  Some love stored procs and others loath them.

Comment: Good for all except the suggestion of using stored procedures, are not recommended.
Using DDD is possible to solve the scenario.

Comment: I think I prefer option one. I assume this means that when a User updates a "Detail", and clicks save. In code, I remove the current "Detail" from the collection of Details on the User, and then I create a new detail with the new information provided, add that "Detail" to the details collection and save that. 

Would this leave the existing detail intact, or would removing the detail for the user, potential remove the detail as well.

Comment: @JonWillis - I think you might need to look more closely at the "removing" of details.  If you start removing objects you are at least breaking FK relationships, which your declarative referential integrity may not allow - or actually deleting the record - which you don't mean to do.  You want to add the new detail, that much is certain.  The question is what you do with the old detail.  That depends on exactly how your database is structured.  I think what you probably mean is UserDetail, not Detail is being removed/replaced.

Comment: I don't believe in blanket statements like "Stored procedures are not recommended."  Every approach has pros and cons.  Some approaches certainly have more cons than pros, but the point is that you should understand what trade-offs you are making and make them deliberately.

Comment: @Joel Brown, You are correct. The Details should never be deleted as an RMA 'may' still reference them. What I wanted to know was if EF could be configured/supported this scenerio. That is when a user updates a Detail, instead of overwriting the existing row in the DB, it creates a new row in Details. It just removes the link in UserDetail from the old row, and adds a new row in UserDetails to the updated detail. I also agree about blanket statements in general, in this case I do like stored procedures although I never use them personally.

Comment: @JonWillis - You can certainly use EF to insert a new details record and either edit the intersection record to point at the new details or delete the old one and insert a new one (UserDetails).  To do this with EF you'd want to have your own business logic (i.e. option 1 in my answer) - which will mean giving up simple "codeless" databinding, or you could use stored procs (i.e. option two, etc.)  You can accomplish what you want with EF, you just have to decide which trade-off you want to make to get there.